# Getting 403-Forbidden error from GetDeb.net repository

Tags: apt, repository, software-sources

Here is my (shortened) output of `sudo apt update` on 16.04:

```
[...]
Ign:2 http://screenshots.getdeb.net xenial-getdeb InRelease                                                           
[...]
Err:13 http://screenshots.getdeb.net xenial-getdeb Release                                      
  403  Forbidden [IP: 104.28.24.125 80]
[...]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I have the GetDeb repository configured manually as described [here](http://www.getdeb.net/updates/ubuntu/16.04/#how_to_install) by creating a file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb-apps.list` with this line:

```
deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb apps
```

This has been working for months until today.

What might be wrong here and can I fix this on my side or is it an error on their server?

Comment: Ran the command at 9:49 PM Saturday, 13 August 2016 Greenwich Mean Time (GMT). Its working here.

Comment: Suggestion & not an answer - run `bleachbit` as root & `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*; sudo apt-get update`. See if it works.

Comment: I added the repository today by installing .deb package and it's working file. even installed a small package from it. May be something screwed up in your network?

Comment: Problem went away by itself, probably it was a misconfiguration on the server side. I'm closing this question.